# Порядок элементов при сравнении на равенство

Tags: java

Можно написать условие вот так:

```
if (repository == null) {}
```

а можно вот так:

```
if (null == repository) {}
```

В чем разница?

Comment: ни в чем. Только порядок аргументов.

Comment: в первом случае `repository` сравнивается с `null`, во втором - `null` с `repository`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Условиями Йоды (Yoda Conditions) называется приём этот. Первой константа ставится, если ошибётесь и используете `=` вместо `==` вы, указал на эту ошибку компилятор вам чтобы. В Java это несущественно, т.к. ошибка будет почти всегда, исключение описано в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594821/181472).

Есть другой случай, когда порядок сравнения имеет значение в Java — `.equals()`. Предположим, у вас есть объект, который вы получаете извне метода и образец для сравнения.

```
if (foo.equals(sample)) {...}
```

Если сравнивать так, что может случиться, что полученный объект будет равен `null` и тогда будет выброшено исключение. А ещё это может быть хитрый объект, в котором `.equals()` переопределено так, чтобы всегда возвращать `true`.

Гораздо надёжнее сравнивать в обратном порядке:

```
if (sample.equals(foo)) {...}
```

Comment: что надежнее в сравнивании в обратном порядке, если у sample Тоже переопределен equals?

Comment: я так понимаю что нет разницы если ни один из обьектов не является константой...

Comment: @Grundy подразумевается, что sample мы получаем надёжным способом. Например, тут же создаём новый объект известного нам класса.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko если оба объекта "ненадёжные", то перед проверкой на `equals` нужно как минимум один из них проверять на `!= null`.

Comment: Упомянуть стоит, от `null` защититься чтобы, [`Objects.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) использовать можно, с седьмой начиная джавы.

Answer (score 13):

Некоторые наркоманы пишут наоборот, чтобы компилятор напомнил, если они напишут "=", вместо "==". Но в Java строгая типизация - `null` к `boolean` не приводится и код с ошибкой не скомпилируется в любом случае, потому разницы нет никакой. В других языках - есть.

**Не** Java, вместо `null` можно считать любую другую константу:

```
if (null = repository) { //compile error
...
}

if (repository = null) { // build success
...
}
```

В Java прокатит один частный случай:

```
if (condition = true) { ... }
```

Comment: а warning никакого не будет в этом случае: `(repository = null)`?

Comment: Более того, в Java будет ошибка компиляции, т.к. null (как результат присваивания) не может быть преобразовано к boolean, но в большинстве Си-подобных языков такой трюк сработает.

Comment: Вот только хотел написать про ошибку в Java :-) Там получается вообще никак не сделать второй код рабочим?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: _прокатит один частный случай_ - второй же с false

Comment: Не Йоды условиями от "частного случая" этого защищаться надо, но недопуская кода индусского! `if(condition)`, `if (!condition)`

Comment: @PavelMayorov кстати, да. Странно, что до сих пор никому (включая меня) не резануло глаза сравнение `bool` через `==` вместо прямого использования.

Comment: @NickVolynkin наверное потому, что речь изначально шла о йода-стиле?)

Answer (score 7):

В принципе, в предыдущих ответах всё уже сказано, просто дополню. 
В *Java* условия Йоды с `==` могут быть полезны только при сравнении `boolean`, в двух случаях.

**1.** Если у вас есть метод, возвращающий `boolean`:

```
public static boolean getBool() { return true; }
```

и вы сравниваете результат этого метода с переменной `boolean`:

```
boolean bln = false;
if (bln == getBool()) {
    //блок if
} else {
    //блок else 
}
```

В этом случае должен выполняться блок else. Но если вы вдруг ошибётесь и напишете:

```
if (bln = getBool()) {
    //блок if
} else {
    //блок else 
}
```

компилятор не выдаст ошибки, и код выполнится, но выполняться будет блок if.
Чтобы не допустить такой ошибки, лучше написать

```
if (getBool() == bln) {
    //блок if
} else {
    //блок else 
}
```

потому что написать `getBool() = bln` по невнимательности компилятор вам не даст.

**2.** Если вы сравниваете объект `Boolean` c `null`:

```
Boolean booleanObject = null;
if (booleanObject == null) { ... }
```

Если в этом случае вы вместо `==` случайно напишете `=`:

```
if (booleanObject = null) { ... }
```

код выполнится, но вы получите `NullPointerException`. А написать

```
if (null = booleanObject) { ... }
```

опять же, компилятор вам не даст.

**P.S.**
Также условие Йоды в Java может быть полезно при сравнении строк с помощью `equals`. Например, если вы напишете

```
if (strVar.equals("string")) {
    //блок if
} else {
    //блок else 
}
```

получите ошибку в случае, если `strVar` было равно `null`, а если напишете

```
if ("string".equals(strVar)) {
    //блок if
} else {
    //блок else 
}
```

попадёте в блок `else` в этом же случае (если `strVar` было равно `null`).

Comment: а разве _NullPointerException_, а не ошибку приведения?

Comment: @Grundy, нет, NullPointerException, я проверяла :)

Comment: @Grundy Почему должна быть ошибка приведения? Boolean - это ссылочный тип, ему вполне можно присваивать null. А вот когда идет попытка сделать unboxing, мы и получаем NPE.

Comment: @free_ze, не, в прошлые разы мне казалось, что как раз ошибка приведения была при сравнении :)

Comment: @Grundy вам казалось.

Comment: Отличные примеры! А почему `equals` только со строками, ведь и другие объекты могут быть `Null`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну да, пример с `equals` не только для строк справедлив, но и для других объектов (всё зависит от того, как у них этот метод `equals` реализован)

Answer (score 3):

Разница в порядке сравнения =)
В Java большой разницы нет, сработает и так и эдак, только если Вы будете сравнивать null со всем подряд то програмисты которые потом будут разбирать Ваш код будут ругаться, что это за индус писал, т.к. не стоит забывать про Code Conventions.